# How to serve multiple files with serve-static?

Tags: node.js, http

I am using serve-static with node to serve basic static html files.

There is a folder containing all of the individual pages you can visit:

```
pages
  -A.html
  -B.html
  -C.html
```

To visit these you simply attach the path to each file in the directory, something like: `localhost:3000/pages/a.html`.

Outside of this directory, there is a `special.html`. I would like this file to be served to the client alongside any of the pages you might be viewing.

So for example if you are at `localhost:3000/pages/a.html`, the client will be served both `a.html` *and* `special.html`. Is this possible? Maybe special could be a wrapper to the pages?

Comment: "No matter what URL you are at"?  Do you mean that no matter what the URL is that is requested, you want to server the exact same static content?  So, your web server doesn't care at all what the URL is?

Comment: @jfriend00 I just updated the post to be more specific.

Comment: What does "served alongside" mean?  A browser requests a page and shows that page.  It doesn't contain any feature to show something along side the requested page.  If you want to show multiple pages, the user either opens multiple tabs in the browser or you create a single page that shows content from two other pages (perhaps with iframes inside the master page).  Still unclear what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, one way you can solve this is to add an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to a, b, and c pages with special.html content. So adding the below line in a, b, and c should do the trick (depending on the path to special.html)

`<iframe id="myIframe" src="./special.html"></iframe>`